# sed: how to add to the beginning of a line on non empty lines

Tags: sed

I have multiple lines in a text file and some are empty.

```
hasjdh lashd 

aksl asldh l lasjdh
```

I want to add * to the start of all the non empty lines.

```
*hasjdh lashd 

*aksl asldh l lasjdh
```

how to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/^./*&/' file
*hasjdh lashd

*aksl asldh l lasjdh
```

Comment: This worked on non-blank lines: `echo 'apple' | sed 's/^./<p>&/ ; s/.$/&<\/p>/'`  --> `<p>apple</p>`

Comment: @VictoriaStuart there's more concise ways to do that - ask a new question if you'd like help.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/\S/s/^/*/' file
```

If the line contains a non-whitespace character, insert an `*` before the first character of that line.

Comment: can you explain this regex

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi the `\S` represents a character which is the dual of `\s` which is whitespace (space, tabs, newlines etc). The `^` is a metacharacter that represents the start of a string, in this case the start of the pattern space a buffer that holds the current line. The `*` represents itself and is inserted between the start of string and the following character or end of line anchor (`$`).

Comment: generally we use `'s/regex/replace/g'` or `'/regex/'` So regex here is `\S/s/^/* `  we see three slashed here.

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi the command consists of an address `/\S/` followed by a substitution `s/^/*/` if the address is true i.e. the line contains a non-whitespace character. N.B. lines that appear empty, may contain spaces or tabs.

Comment: OK. thank you. I am completely new to this. i go it. So `\S` is the non whitespace character. So if any non whitespace character is found in the line then it acts.